# laravel sum and join taking much time to fetch records

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 tables transactions and users tables which both have over 100k records.
In my transaction table, i have amount as one of my columns which i want to sum up and order by the highest amount, but it takes longer time to fetch records.

```
$data = DB::table('transactions')
->join('users', 'users.uuid', '=', 'transactions.user');

$data->select(DB::raw('sum(transactions.amount) as amount, transactions.user, transactions.rate, transactions.currency, transactions.updated_at, transactions.created_at, users.firstname, users.lastname, users.username'));

$data->groupBy('transactions.user')
->orderByRaw('SUM(amount) desc');
$datas = $data->take(15)->get();
```

Please help! I dont want to use "hasMany" or "belongsTo" or "with" because I don't know much about it

Answer (score 0):

In my experience when you need to work large amounts of data its better to let MySQL do it directly using only one DB::raw statement something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(transactions.amount) AS amount,
        transactions.user,
        transactions.rate,
        transactions.currency,
        transactions.updated_at,
        transactions.created_at,
        users.firstname,
        users.lastname,
        users.username
    FROM
        transactions
    JOIN users ON users.uuid = transactions.user
    GROUP BY
        transactions.user
    ORDER BY
        SUM(amount)
    DESC
    LIMIT 15";

    DB::table('users')->selectRaw($sql)->get();
```

You need to improve it to better suit your needs...

Comment: Ok @chico let me try it now and hope it won't be slow in executing records, thanks so much, I'll revert soon

Comment: your query is wrong, im getting errors here

Comment: I was pretty sure it was wrong, i do not know your table structure, I only posted it as a guide on how can it be done ...

Comment: Ok cool, can i please post my table structure for you to take a look at it?